# Why does pygame show a black window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Imports

```
#Imports
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
```

Display

```
pygame.init() #initializes pygame window
pygame.display.set_caption('Parkour') #titlebar caption

Bg=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0,32) #sets main surface

"""--------------------------------------------------------------------------"""
```

Event loop

```
gameActive = True
while gameActive:
    #print (event)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameActive = False     
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Background (ISSUE) Yeah I'm a beginner, but shouldn't this fill the screen then update it? Bg is true so it should constantly run right?

```
#Background
Bg = True
while Bg:
    screen.fill((0,0,255))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Please put all your code snippets together to make a [mre] for others to run.

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore the variable `Bg` is the [Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) which is associated to the window:

> ```py
> Bg=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0,32) #sets main surface
> ```

Do not use the same variable name for a boolean state:

> ```py
> Bg = True
> ```

I recommend to change the name of the display surface (e.g. screen), because you've used this name in `screen.fill((0,0,255))`, too:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0,32) #sets main surface
```

---

Of course you have fill the background and to update the display in the main application loop. The main application has to

- handle the events
- clear the display
- draw the scene
- update the display

continuously in every frame.

e.g.:

```py
#Imports
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init() #initializes pygame window
pygame.display.set_caption('Parkour') #titlebar caption

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0,32) #sets main surface

# main application loop
gameActive = True
while gameActive:

    # handle the events in the event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameActive = False 

    # clear the display
    screen.fill((0,0,255))

    # draw the scene
    # [...] draw things here

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
```